# How to center the text within an Angular Material Button?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an angular material button:

```
<a mat-raised-button class="buttons-class" color="accent">Hello!</a>
```

And I have increased its size:

```
.buttons-class {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 210px !important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Now, I wish to center the text (`Hello!`) within it. Currently the text is offset like this:

[image]

Putting the text in a span or div and using the standard centering techniques didn't work.

Comment: There is a inner container in the button which also should be increased to the same size as the outer button.

Comment: Yes, wrapping the text within the button in a span, resizing to fit the outer button and centering its contents worked. The weird thing was that the div was shifted to the right by `16px`, but I used `margin-left: -16px;` to fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-deep
::ng-deep shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views
and styling any class

```
::ng-deep.buttons-class {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 210px !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using `::ng-deep` doesn't respect the height and width (the size of the button shrinks to fit the text). Using ng-deep with inline `style` leads to the same problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: please test this code           ```.buttons-class {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 210px !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following styles please.

```
.buttons-class {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 210px !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```